# Filter a table and add order to result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's imagine I have a Table as follows:

| Area | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.5 |
| A | 2 | 1.2 |
| B | 3 | 1.1 |
| B | 4 | 0.8 |
| C | 5 | 1.0 |
| B | 6 | 0.6 |
| A | 7 | 1.5 |

What I want to achieve, is filtering the table based on `Area` value, order the values by `ID`s and return the `Value` field and relative record orders for that specific `Area`.
So, for example, If I filter the table by `Area = B`, I want to obtain the Table

| Area | Order | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1 | 1.1 |
| B | 2 | 0.8 |
| B | 3 | 0.6 |

Thanks to anyone who would like to help me!

Comment: What is your current SQL query you could write to get that result, and what problem you face to archive that expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function.

```
SELECT Area
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Area ORDER BY ID) AS Order
  , Value 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE Area = 'B' -- You can try without where, you'll get order by each area
```